# Mezzanine overextends() template tag examples?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, mezzanine

I've been searching but there no examples of Mezzanine overextends()template tag, which allows you to extend a template with the same name. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While we still support django-1.8, note that `overextends` is deprecated because starting in django-1.9, `extends` supports recursive template extension.

There are several examples you can check out in my project [cartridge-downloads](https://github.com/ryneeverett/cartridge-downloads), but unless you're stuck on django-1.8 or writing a reusable app that supports django-1.8, there is no reason to use the `overextends` template tag.

Comment: Ryne, when will Mezzanine update the docs, it did not mention about deprecation of overextends and I suspect many other?

Comment: On the other hand, I'd rather eliminate this section entirely. I think I got some resistance on that before though, so we'll see how [my PR](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/pull/1687) is received.