# Invalid block tag on line 1: 'overextends'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I'm upgrading  mezzanine/django application form python 2.7/Mezzanine 4.3.1 to python 3.7/mezzanine 5.0.0.

When when running the application in 3.7/mezzanine 5.0.0. I get the error     `django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 1: 'overextends'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

I guess it must come from the file myProject/myProject/templates/admin/base_site.html:

```
{% overextends "admin/base_site.html" %}

{% block extrahead  %}
    {{block.super}}
    <style type="text/css">
        div.cke_chrome {
            margin-left: 130px;
        }
    </style>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/statfi-editor.css" />
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/statfi_csrf.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

since if I remove the 1st line `{% overextends "admin/base_site.html" %}` the borwser shows empty admin/-page.

I tried to fix by adding buildins key into TEMPLATES setting:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'builtins': ['overextends.templatetags.overextends_tags'],
        }
    },
]
```

but that would require installing overextends-module.
When installing it I got: `django-overextends 0.4.3 requires django<2.0,>=1.8, but you have django 2.2 which is incompatible.`

Are there any other means to solve the problem than just downgrading both mezzanine and django version in order to get that overextends module into use ?

Comment: this should be {% extends "admin/base_site.html" %} -  as far as I know overextends is debrecated

Comment: overextends is pypi package and you need to install it first. Then add it to your project installed_apps etc. See example from here https://pypi.org/project/django-overextends/

Comment: @Razenstein, yes, seems so as there doesn't  seem to be any module compatible with Django 2.2. How should it be replaced on later django releases?

Comment: did you try it with just {% extends "...." %} ?  I am not deep in the topic, maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39924647/mezzanine-overextends-template-tag-examples

Comment: @Razenstein Great thanks, it worked !